# getfield() in C, inconsistent

Tags: c, csv

I have this ginormous CSV file that i want to dissect. But i noticed not all data was coming thru and i cant figure out why.

When i have 2 getfield's in the fprintf. I get both answers, when i have 3, the middle is allways NULL, when i have 4, both middle ones are NULL. 
So why do i allways get 2 answers and why are the middle ones allways NULL?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
const char* getfield(char* line, int num){
    const char* tok;
    for (tok = strtok(line, ","); tok && *tok ; tok = strtok(NULL, ",\n")){
        if (!--num){
            return tok;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
int main(){
    FILE* stream = fopen("perf log (paralel encoding disabled).CSV", "r");
    FILE *f = fopen("file2.html", "w+");
    if (f == NULL){
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char* html1 = "<!DOCTYPE html> \n<html> \n<head> \n <title></title> \n</head> \n<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'> </script>\n <body> \n";
    fprintf(f, "%s", html1 );
    int i = 0;
    char line1[102400];
    while (fgets(line1, 102400, stream)){
        char* tmp1 = strdup(line1);
        if(i > -1 && i<60000){
            fprintf(f,"[%i , %s  , %s , %s ] <br>",i, getfield(tmp1, 1),  getfield(tmp1, 2), getfield(tmp1, 3), );
        }
        free(tmp1);
        i++;
    }
    char* html4 = "   \n </body> \n </html> \n";
    fprintf(f, "%s", html4);
    fclose(f);
}
```

some of the output

```
[0 , Date , (null) , "Virtual Memory Commited [MB]" ] 
[1 , 13.3.2018 , (null) , 7226 ] 
[2 , 13.3.2018 , (null) , 7237 ] 
[3 , 13.3.2018 , (null) , 7226 ] 
[4 , 13.3.2018 , (null) , 7298 ] 
[5 , 13.3.2018 , (null) , 8011 ]
```

Comment: You realize that `strtok()` both mutates the source sequence *and*  returns a pointer to it (instead of a pointer to a copy)?

Comment: Not really, i'm fairly new to C. :)

Comment: Any particular reason that you need to use C? There are easier languages for parsing text (including CSV) files. Try Perl, Ruby or Python, if you want something mainstream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `getfield()` modifies the buffer, overwriting separators with null bytes, so the next time it is called, only the first field is accessible.
- the order in which function arguments are evaluated is unspecified, so is which call to `getfield()` succeeds among the 3 calls in the argument list to `fprintf`.
- `strtok()` is rarely the right tool for parsing: it will consider any sequence of separators to be a single separator, which is invalid for CSV files as empty fields will cause incorrect parsing.

You should change `getfield()` to allocate the string or copy it to a destination buffer.

Here is a modified version that allocates the return value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *getfield(const char* line, int num) {
    const char *p = line;
    size_t len;
    char *res;
    for (;;) {
        len = strcspn(p, ";\n");
        if (--num <= 0)
            break;
        p += len;
        if (*p == ';')
            p++;
    }
    res = malloc(len + 1);
    if (res) {
        memcpy(res, p, len);
        res[len] = '\0';
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    FILE *stream = fopen("perf log (paralel encoding disabled).CSV", "r");
    if (stream == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening input file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    FILE *f = fopen("file2.html", "w+");
    if (f == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening output file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    const char *html1 = "<!DOCTYPE html> \n<html> \n<head> \n <title></title> \n</head>\n"
                        "<script type='text/javascript' "
                        "src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'> </script>\n <body> \n";
    fprintf(f, "%s", html1);
    int i = 0;
    char line1[102400];
    while (fgets(line1, 102400, stream)) {
        char *tmp1 = getfield(line1, 1);
        char *tmp2 = getfield(line1, 2);
        char *tmp3 = getfield(line1, 3);
        if (i > -1 && i < 60000) {
            fprintf(f,"[%i , %s  , %s , %s ] <br>", i, tmp1, tmp2, tmp3);
        }
        free(tmp1);
        free(tmp2);
        free(tmp3);
        i++;
    }
    const char *html4 = "   \n </body> \n </html> \n";
    fprintf(f, "%s", html4);
    fclose(stream);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```